# What do the sub-stats on a weapon mean?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

When a weapon is examined in your inventory, the right side of the screen has 3 sections as part of the description.

- The top section has a description box for the weapon, *flavor text* if you will.
- The middle section has numerical stats for the weapon, the damage it does.
- The bottom section has slots of information for inherent abilites, special effects, and patches that the weapon provides. (this is where elemental damage goes, hence my confusion)

In the *Middle Section*, the numerical stats are divided into two lines, the top line has the exact damage the weapon does, such as; **123-175(x2)**.

The bottom line sometimes has an icon, such as angel wings, flames, snowflakes, ect, and a +# following the icon. **What does this part of the statistical information mean?**

Comment: Having never played the game or seen the weapon screen in question, it sounds to me like you're looking at Damage Range (number of hits), with the bottom line filling in elemental damage: Fire, Ice, and... holy? with their corresponding bonus damage numbers.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Edited to better explain why I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing I have confirmed that this **is** elemental damage, however it is not *extra* elemental damage. This stat seems to reflect the weapons natural damage element.

I took my Staff of Winter (+50 frost) and attacked an elf that was weak to frost damage, and he took additional damage as if from a frost attack. **During this combat sequence I had no strap-ons equipped to my weapon, nor did I have any active buffs or anything else that would have added elemental damage to my attack.**

Note: My weapon *did not do X normal damage and then X frost damage, it just did X damage*, and a **WEAK** icon appeared near the floating dmg numbers.

I can only assume then that the *+50 Frost* means that 50% of my damage dealt with the weapon is Frost Damage. If anyone has any ideas on how to test this more extensively they would be very welcome.

Comment: It definitely doesn't mean a percentage. I'm pretty sure it *is* additional to the base, and I think the game is just obfuscating the fact that your damage is broken down a bit more than is displayed; +50 Frost means literally 50 frost damage, etc. (This would be consistent with the effect you get from various +elemental damage stickers and strapons).

Comment: Assuming you were correct, is that damage included in the listed damage, or should I add that after the listed damage to have an idea of how much damage a weapon does?

Comment: Not sure. This should be easy to test/double check with one of the flat +Elemental Damage strap ons (there are a bunch).

Comment: I'm not following you

Comment: Pretty sure the elemental damage comes after the actual damage. When you hit an enemy with a weapon that does elemental damage you will see two numbers appear after the hit. The first and typically larger one is the normal damage and the second and differently colored (colored to the element) is the elemental damage. So therefore the damage is applied seperately from the normal weapon damage.

Comment: @Dupree3 thats why I think the weapon itself isn't doing extra frost dmg, but inherent frost dmg

Comment: The weapon does do the frost damage still since its the attachment on the weapon though...

Comment: There is no attachment on this weapon, I'm not sure what your trying to say.